# I'm trying to parse information from a list of URLs but my code parses the same page each time

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to parse the a list of URLS saved with UTF8 format and named links in the python idle folder. One example would be:

'https://www.safirstores.com/%D8%A2%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B4%DB%8C#/availability=1/sort=p.sort_order/order=ASC/limit=32/page=44'

but when I try to run my code, it will parse info from the first part of URL everytime. It's like parsing the following URL:

'https://www.safirstores.com/%D8%A2%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B4%DB%8C#'

note that there is # in the end of url. and I think this # prevents my urls to change. I don't know why.

here is my full code:

```
import requests
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

with open('links.txt','r', encoding="utf8") as f:
urls = f.read().split()

with open('promo.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f_output:
csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
csv_output.writerow(['name', 'links', 'price'])

for url in urls:
    try:
        print(url)
        source = requests.get(url).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
        divs = soup.find_all('div', class_='caption')
        if divs:
            for div in divs:
                price = div.find('p', {'class':'price'}).text.strip()
                print(price)
                name = div.find('h4', {'class':'name'}).text.strip()
                print(name)
                links = div.find('a')['href']
                print(links)
                print()
                csv_output.writerow([name, links, price])
        else:
            print("Finished")
            break
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

and my URL list looks like this:

```
https://www.safirstores.com/آرایشی#/availability=1/sort=p.sort_order/order=ASC/limit=32/page=1
https://www.safirstores.com/آرایشی#/availability=1/sort=p.sort_order/order=ASC/limit=32/page=2
https://www.safirstores.com/آرایشی#/availability=1/sort=p.sort_order/order=ASC/limit=32/page=3
```

What should I do to prevent such problem?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Is `source = requests.get(urls).text` supposed to be `source = requests.get(url).text`? Try adding some debug prints, e.g. `print(urls)`, `print(url)`and so on..

Comment: I did use print to see each step. It seems that url do change but the results doesn't. And you are right about URL instead of URLS but it doesn't change the results.

Comment: Couldn't replicate your problem using requests, and a `links.txt` with your  list of 3 urls. A random sample from your 2nd url looks like this: `432,000 تومان
ایو سن لوران خط چشم شاکینگ 01
https://www.safirstores.com/آرایشی/YSL-EYE LINER PEN FAUX CILS SHOKING-976-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.safirstores.com/index.php'

payload = {
'route': 'module/journal2_super_filter/products',
'module_id': '54'}

with open('promo.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(['name', 'links', 'price'])


for page in range(1, 100):
    try:
        form = {
        'filters': '/availability=1/sort=p.sort_order/order=ASC/limit=32/page=%s' %page,
        'route': 'product/category',
        'path': '238',
        'manufacturer_id': '',
        'search':'' ,
        'tag':'' }

        source = requests.post(url, params=payload, data=form)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'html.parser')
        divs = soup.find_all('div', class_='caption')
        if divs:
            for div in divs:
                price = div.find('p', {'class':'price'}).text.strip()
                print(price)
                name = div.find('h4', {'class':'name'}).text.strip()
                print(name)
                links = div.find('a')['href']
                print(links)
                print()
                csv_output.writerow([name, links, price])
        else:
            print("Finished")
            break
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```